# Print all colorings of a 3x3 grid

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, graphical-output, combinatorics, grid

You have a 3x3 grid. Each cell can be colored black or white. Display all 512 of these colorings. Fewest bytes wins.

You can display the grids in any formation as long as they are visually separated and the spacing looks regular. You may use ASCII art or images. Any two distinct visible symbols or colors can be used for black and white. Any whitespace is fine as long as the result is visually correct.

**Example output:**

```
...
...
...

...
...
..X

...
...
.X.

...
...
.XX

...
...
X..

...
...
X.X

...
...
XX.

...
...
XXX

...
..X
...

...
..X
..X

...
..X
.X.

...
..X
.XX

...
..X
X..

...
..X
X.X

...
..X
XX.

...
..X
XXX

...
.X.
...

...
.X.
..X

...
.X.
.X.

...
.X.
.XX

...
.X.
X..

...
.X.
X.X

...
.X.
XX.

...
.X.
XXX

...
.XX
...

...
.XX
..X

...
.XX
.X.

...
.XX
.XX

...
.XX
X..

...
.XX
X.X

...
.XX
XX.

...
.XX
XXX

...
X..
...

...
X..
..X

...
X..
.X.

...
X..
.XX

...
X..
X..

...
X..
X.X

...
X..
XX.

...
X..
XXX

...
X.X
...

...
X.X
..X

...
X.X
.X.

...
X.X
.XX

...
X.X
X..

...
X.X
X.X

...
X.X
XX.

...
X.X
XXX

...
XX.
...

...
XX.
..X

...
XX.
.X.

...
XX.
.XX

...
XX.
X..

...
XX.
X.X

...
XX.
XX.

...
XX.
XXX

...
XXX
...

...
XXX
..X

...
XXX
.X.

...
XXX
.XX

...
XXX
X..

...
XXX
X.X

...
XXX
XX.

...
XXX
XXX

..X
...
...

..X
...
..X

..X
...
.X.

..X
...
.XX

..X
...
X..

..X
...
X.X

..X
...
XX.

..X
...
XXX

..X
..X
...

..X
..X
..X

..X
..X
.X.

..X
..X
.XX

..X
..X
X..

..X
..X
X.X

..X
..X
XX.

..X
..X
XXX

..X
.X.
...

..X
.X.
..X

..X
.X.
.X.

..X
.X.
.XX

..X
.X.
X..

..X
.X.
X.X

..X
.X.
XX.

..X
.X.
XXX

..X
.XX
...

..X
.XX
..X

..X
.XX
.X.

..X
.XX
.XX

..X
.XX
X..

..X
.XX
X.X

..X
.XX
XX.

..X
.XX
XXX

..X
X..
...

..X
X..
..X

..X
X..
.X.

..X
X..
.XX

..X
X..
X..

..X
X..
X.X

..X
X..
XX.

..X
X..
XXX

..X
X.X
...

..X
X.X
..X

..X
X.X
.X.

..X
X.X
.XX

..X
X.X
X..

..X
X.X
X.X

..X
X.X
XX.

..X
X.X
XXX

..X
XX.
...

..X
XX.
..X

..X
XX.
.X.

..X
XX.
.XX

..X
XX.
X..

..X
XX.
X.X

..X
XX.
XX.

..X
XX.
XXX

..X
XXX
...

..X
XXX
..X

..X
XXX
.X.

..X
XXX
.XX

..X
XXX
X..

..X
XXX
X.X

..X
XXX
XX.

..X
XXX
XXX

.X.
...
...

.X.
...
..X

.X.
...
.X.

.X.
...
.XX

.X.
...
X..

.X.
...
X.X

.X.
...
XX.

.X.
...
XXX

.X.
..X
...

.X.
..X
..X

.X.
..X
.X.

.X.
..X
.XX

.X.
..X
X..

.X.
..X
X.X

.X.
..X
XX.

.X.
..X
XXX

.X.
.X.
...

.X.
.X.
..X

.X.
.X.
.X.

.X.
.X.
.XX

.X.
.X.
X..

.X.
.X.
X.X

.X.
.X.
XX.

.X.
.X.
XXX

.X.
.XX
...

.X.
.XX
..X

.X.
.XX
.X.

.X.
.XX
.XX

.X.
.XX
X..

.X.
.XX
X.X

.X.
.XX
XX.

.X.
.XX
XXX

.X.
X..
...

.X.
X..
..X

.X.
X..
.X.

.X.
X..
.XX

.X.
X..
X..

.X.
X..
X.X

.X.
X..
XX.

.X.
X..
XXX

.X.
X.X
...

.X.
X.X
..X

.X.
X.X
.X.

.X.
X.X
.XX

.X.
X.X
X..

.X.
X.X
X.X

.X.
X.X
XX.

.X.
X.X
XXX

.X.
XX.
...

.X.
XX.
..X

.X.
XX.
.X.

.X.
XX.
.XX

.X.
XX.
X..

.X.
XX.
X.X

.X.
XX.
XX.

.X.
XX.
XXX

.X.
XXX
...

.X.
XXX
..X

.X.
XXX
.X.

.X.
XXX
.XX

.X.
XXX
X..

.X.
XXX
X.X

.X.
XXX
XX.

.X.
XXX
XXX

.XX
...
...

.XX
...
..X

.XX
...
.X.

.XX
...
.XX

.XX
...
X..

.XX
...
X.X

.XX
...
XX.

.XX
...
XXX

.XX
..X
...

.XX
..X
..X

.XX
..X
.X.

.XX
..X
.XX

.XX
..X
X..

.XX
..X
X.X

.XX
..X
XX.

.XX
..X
XXX

.XX
.X.
...

.XX
.X.
..X

.XX
.X.
.X.

.XX
.X.
.XX

.XX
.X.
X..

.XX
.X.
X.X

.XX
.X.
XX.

.XX
.X.
XXX

.XX
.XX
...

.XX
.XX
..X

.XX
.XX
.X.

.XX
.XX
.XX

.XX
.XX
X..

.XX
.XX
X.X

.XX
.XX
XX.

.XX
.XX
XXX

.XX
X..
...

.XX
X..
..X

.XX
X..
.X.

.XX
X..
.XX

.XX
X..
X..

.XX
X..
X.X

.XX
X..
XX.

.XX
X..
XXX

.XX
X.X
...

.XX
X.X
..X

.XX
X.X
.X.

.XX
X.X
.XX

.XX
X.X
X..

.XX
X.X
X.X

.XX
X.X
XX.

.XX
X.X
XXX

.XX
XX.
...

.XX
XX.
..X

.XX
XX.
.X.

.XX
XX.
.XX

.XX
XX.
X..

.XX
XX.
X.X

.XX
XX.
XX.

.XX
XX.
XXX

.XX
XXX
...

.XX
XXX
..X

.XX
XXX
.X.

.XX
XXX
.XX

.XX
XXX
X..

.XX
XXX
X.X

.XX
XXX
XX.

.XX
XXX
XXX

X..
...
...

X..
...
..X

X..
...
.X.

X..
...
.XX

X..
...
X..

X..
...
X.X

X..
...
XX.

X..
...
XXX

X..
..X
...

X..
..X
..X

X..
..X
.X.

X..
..X
.XX

X..
..X
X..

X..
..X
X.X

X..
..X
XX.

X..
..X
XXX

X..
.X.
...

X..
.X.
..X

X..
.X.
.X.

X..
.X.
.XX

X..
.X.
X..

X..
.X.
X.X

X..
.X.
XX.

X..
.X.
XXX

X..
.XX
...

X..
.XX
..X

X..
.XX
.X.

X..
.XX
.XX

X..
.XX
X..

X..
.XX
X.X

X..
.XX
XX.

X..
.XX
XXX

X..
X..
...

X..
X..
..X

X..
X..
.X.

X..
X..
.XX

X..
X..
X..

X..
X..
X.X

X..
X..
XX.

X..
X..
XXX

X..
X.X
...

X..
X.X
..X

X..
X.X
.X.

X..
X.X
.XX

X..
X.X
X..

X..
X.X
X.X

X..
X.X
XX.

X..
X.X
XXX

X..
XX.
...

X..
XX.
..X

X..
XX.
.X.

X..
XX.
.XX

X..
XX.
X..

X..
XX.
X.X

X..
XX.
XX.

X..
XX.
XXX

X..
XXX
...

X..
XXX
..X

X..
XXX
.X.

X..
XXX
.XX

X..
XXX
X..

X..
XXX
X.X

X..
XXX
XX.

X..
XXX
XXX

X.X
...
...

X.X
...
..X

X.X
...
.X.

X.X
...
.XX

X.X
...
X..

X.X
...
X.X

X.X
...
XX.

X.X
...
XXX

X.X
..X
...

X.X
..X
..X

X.X
..X
.X.

X.X
..X
.XX

X.X
..X
X..

X.X
..X
X.X

X.X
..X
XX.

X.X
..X
XXX

X.X
.X.
...

X.X
.X.
..X

X.X
.X.
.X.

X.X
.X.
.XX

X.X
.X.
X..

X.X
.X.
X.X

X.X
.X.
XX.

X.X
.X.
XXX

X.X
.XX
...

X.X
.XX
..X

X.X
.XX
.X.

X.X
.XX
.XX

X.X
.XX
X..

X.X
.XX
X.X

X.X
.XX
XX.

X.X
.XX
XXX

X.X
X..
...

X.X
X..
..X

X.X
X..
.X.

X.X
X..
.XX

X.X
X..
X..

X.X
X..
X.X

X.X
X..
XX.

X.X
X..
XXX

X.X
X.X
...

X.X
X.X
..X

X.X
X.X
.X.

X.X
X.X
.XX

X.X
X.X
X..

X.X
X.X
X.X

X.X
X.X
XX.

X.X
X.X
XXX

X.X
XX.
...

X.X
XX.
..X

X.X
XX.
.X.

X.X
XX.
.XX

X.X
XX.
X..

X.X
XX.
X.X

X.X
XX.
XX.

X.X
XX.
XXX

X.X
XXX
...

X.X
XXX
..X

X.X
XXX
.X.

X.X
XXX
.XX

X.X
XXX
X..

X.X
XXX
X.X

X.X
XXX
XX.

X.X
XXX
XXX

XX.
...
...

XX.
...
..X

XX.
...
.X.

XX.
...
.XX

XX.
...
X..

XX.
...
X.X

XX.
...
XX.

XX.
...
XXX

XX.
..X
...

XX.
..X
..X

XX.
..X
.X.

XX.
..X
.XX

XX.
..X
X..

XX.
..X
X.X

XX.
..X
XX.

XX.
..X
XXX

XX.
.X.
...

XX.
.X.
..X

XX.
.X.
.X.

XX.
.X.
.XX

XX.
.X.
X..

XX.
.X.
X.X

XX.
.X.
XX.

XX.
.X.
XXX

XX.
.XX
...

XX.
.XX
..X

XX.
.XX
.X.

XX.
.XX
.XX

XX.
.XX
X..

XX.
.XX
X.X

XX.
.XX
XX.

XX.
.XX
XXX

XX.
X..
...

XX.
X..
..X

XX.
X..
.X.

XX.
X..
.XX

XX.
X..
X..

XX.
X..
X.X

XX.
X..
XX.

XX.
X..
XXX

XX.
X.X
...

XX.
X.X
..X

XX.
X.X
.X.

XX.
X.X
.XX

XX.
X.X
X..

XX.
X.X
X.X

XX.
X.X
XX.

XX.
X.X
XXX

XX.
XX.
...

XX.
XX.
..X

XX.
XX.
.X.

XX.
XX.
.XX

XX.
XX.
X..

XX.
XX.
X.X

XX.
XX.
XX.

XX.
XX.
XXX

XX.
XXX
...

XX.
XXX
..X

XX.
XXX
.X.

XX.
XXX
.XX

XX.
XXX
X..

XX.
XXX
X.X

XX.
XXX
XX.

XX.
XXX
XXX

XXX
...
...

XXX
...
..X

XXX
...
.X.

XXX
...
.XX

XXX
...
X..

XXX
...
X.X

XXX
...
XX.

XXX
...
XXX

XXX
..X
...

XXX
..X
..X

XXX
..X
.X.

XXX
..X
.XX

XXX
..X
X..

XXX
..X
X.X

XXX
..X
XX.

XXX
..X
XXX

XXX
.X.
...

XXX
.X.
..X

XXX
.X.
.X.

XXX
.X.
.XX

XXX
.X.
X..

XXX
.X.
X.X

XXX
.X.
XX.

XXX
.X.
XXX

XXX
.XX
...

XXX
.XX
..X

XXX
.XX
.X.

XXX
.XX
.XX

XXX
.XX
X..

XXX
.XX
X.X

XXX
.XX
XX.

XXX
.XX
XXX

XXX
X..
...

XXX
X..
..X

XXX
X..
.X.

XXX
X..
.XX

XXX
X..
X..

XXX
X..
X.X

XXX
X..
XX.

XXX
X..
XXX

XXX
X.X
...

XXX
X.X
..X

XXX
X.X
.X.

XXX
X.X
.XX

XXX
X.X
X..

XXX
X.X
X.X

XXX
X.X
XX.

XXX
X.X
XXX

XXX
XX.
...

XXX
XX.
..X

XXX
XX.
.X.

XXX
XX.
.XX

XXX
XX.
X..

XXX
XX.
X.X

XXX
XX.
XX.

XXX
XX.
XXX

XXX
XXX
...

XXX
XXX
..X

XXX
XXX
.X.

XXX
XXX
.XX

XXX
XXX
X..

XXX
XXX
X.X

XXX
XXX
XX.

XXX
XXX
XXX
```

Comment: @edc65 xnor made the edit, and Filipe approved it (after which I purged the comments). I just added tags.

Comment: Can we move the example to a PasteBin? It’s anemic to scroll as of right now. Besides, this is just the power set of the input squared, divided into lines of the input where the `1`s and `0`s are replaced by `X` and `.`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## K, 11 bytes

```
(3 3#)'!9#2
```

Output example:

```
((0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 0)
 (0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 0 1)
 (0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 1 0)
 (0 0 0
  0 0 0
  0 1 1)
…
```

This is K's native prettyprinted representation of a list of matrices, which I think is sufficient for the problem spec. Each matrix is delimited by an enclosing set of parentheses.

And a quick sanity check to demonstrate that 512 matrices are constructed:

```
  #(3 3#)'!9#2
512
```

Very straightforward. Most of the work is in the `!`. First we generate a 9-long vector of 2s using "take" (`9#2`). Then, we make use of the "odometer" monadic form of `!`- a few examples illustrate its behavior:

```
  !2 2
(0 0
 0 1
 1 0
 1 1)
  !2 3
(0 0
 0 1
 0 2
 1 0
 1 1
 1 2)
  !2 2 2
(0 0 0
 0 0 1
 0 1 0
 0 1 1
 1 0 0
 1 0 1
 1 1 0
 1 1 1)
```

Then simply do a 3x3 reshape (`(3 3#)`) of each (`'`) of the 9-length 0/1 vectors.

Answer (score 35):

## Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
Image/@{0,1}~Tuples~{3,3}
```

Gives an array with all the grids as images, which is also directly displayed on screen:

[image]

(Cropped so as not to blow up the post unnecessarily.)

Comment: upvoted for being the prettiest output

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript, 77 <s>80</s>

Revised after the revision of the OP. Now we have a question, so here is an answer.

Run the snippet in any browser to test.

```js
// Test: redefine console to have output inside the snippet

console = { log: function(x) { O.textContent+=x+'\n\n';} }

// Solution: 77 chars (note, distinct outputs to console are automatically separed)
  
for(i=511;++i<1024;)console.log(i.toString(2).slice(1).match(/.../g).join`
`)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Old post: graphic display  in a browser, with javascript and canvas. ~300 byte of code (can be made shorter).

Run the snippet below.

```js
d=8, // Min block size
C.width=d*64,C.height=d*128,
T=C.getContext('2d')

for(i=0;i<512;i++)
{
  bx=4*(i/32|0)
  by=4*(i%32)
  for(b=1,j=0;j<9;j++,b+=b)    
  {
    if(b&i) 
      x=j/3|0, y=j%3, T.fillRect((bx+x)*d,(by+y)*d,d,d);
  }
  T.strokeRect(bx*d,by*d,d*3,d*3);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=C></canvas>
```

Comment: If you specify `(ES6)`, you can replace `.join('\n')` with .join`
` (literal newline, not space... stupid comment formatting) to save 3 bytes

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes, template string was already implemented in Firefox 14 months ago, but I was not aware of that. Edit the code after so much time is a little necrobumping

Answer (score 7):

## Matlab, 33

```
reshape(dec2bin(0:511,9)',3,3,[])
```

Was kind of fiddly to get the dimensions correct, but I am very happy with the result!

Answer (score 6):

### POWERSHELL - 65

```
0..511|%{[convert]::ToString($_,2).padleft(9,'0')-split"(.{3})"}
```

result

```
000

000

000


000

000

001


000

000

010


000

000

011
```

confirmation

```
(0..511|%{[convert]::ToString($_,2).padleft(9,'0')-split"(.{3})"} | measure -Line).lines/3

512
```

edit inspired by the mathematica answer's display of results-617

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$a=new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap 992,496
$g=[Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($a)
$b=@{};$y=@{};$i=$c=$d=$z=$k=$l=$m=0;
0..511|%{$y[$d++]=[convert]::ToString($_,2).padleft(9,'0')}
while($m-lt480){while($l-lt496){for($z=($m+0);$z-lt($m+32);$z++){
      $y[$z].tochararray()|%{if($_-eq"0"){$b[$i++]=[Drawing.Brushes]::Black}
        else{$b[$i++]=[Drawing.Brushes]::White}
      }
      for($j=($l+0);$j-lt($l+30);$j+=10){
        ($k+0),($k+10),($k+20)|%{$g.FillRectangle($b[$c++],$_,$j,10,10)}
      }$k+=31
    }$k=0;$l+=31;$m+=32
  }
}$a.save("$HOME/3X3_Grid.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, 49 bytes

```python
i=2048;exec"print bin(i/4)[i%4*3+3:][:3];i+=1;"*i
```

Split the binary expansion of `i`. The length-10 binary values 512 through 1023 are used, cutting off the initial 1 (and prefix `0b`). These are split into chunks of 3 as windows `[3:6]`, `[6:9]`, `[9:12]`, and `[12:15]`, with the last one blank to make a blank line. Iterating over the four slices is collapsed with the outer loop of counting through 512 numbers with the divmod trick.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 12 bytes

```
2,9m*3f/N*N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2%2C9m*3f%2FN*N*)

Uses `0` and `1` as the distinct characters.

### Explanation

```
2,  e# Push [0 1].
9m* e# Generate all 9-tuples of 0s and 1s.
3f/ e# Split each 9-tuple into 3 subarrays of length 3.
N*  e# Join all those grids with newlines.
N*  e# Put newlines between all the length-3 arrays.
```

An alternative (still 12 byte) solution is

```
2,3m*3m*N*N*
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```
r x=sequence[x,x,x]
u=unlines
f=putStr$u$map u$r$r".X"
```

`f` gives the same output as in the challenge description, i.e. it starts with

```
...
...
...

...
...
..X

...
...
.X.
```

Edit: @Mauris found 3 bytes to save. Thanks!

Comment: I think `r x=sequence[x,x,x]` does the same thing and is shorter.

Comment: @Mauris: you're right. Edited my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 86 bytes

```
0.upto(511).map{|i|i.to_s(2).rjust(9,'0')}.each{|j|p j[0..2];p j[3..5];p j[6..8];puts}
```

Mine prints with quotes because `p` is shorter than `puts`, but it does still fit the rules.

Answer (score 3):

## C# - 111

```
for(int i=0;i<512;i++)Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Convert.ToString(i,2).PadLeft(9,'0'),"(.{3})","$1\r\n"));
```

Converts every int to its binary representation and splits every 3 chars.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 95 Bytes

Distinct characters are `0` and `1`, each block is separated by `\n\n`.

```py
n='\n';print(n+n).join(y[:3]+n+y[3:6]+n+y[-3:]for y in[bin(x)[2:].zfill(9)for x in range(512)])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 81

```
import re
for i in range(512):print re.sub('(.{3})','\\1\n',bin(i)[2:].zfill(9))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 92 bytes

```rb
0.upto(511){|i|("%09d"%i.to_s(2)).scan(/.{3}/).map{|j|j.scan(/./)}.map{|j|puts j.join};puts}
```

Counts in `0`s and `1`s, and each block is separated by an empty line (`\n\n`)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
V^`T9jbc3Nk
```

[**Try it here!**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V%5E%60T9jbc3Nk&debug=0)

Thanks @Jakube :)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 68 bytes

Prints the exact same output as the example given in the question

```
puts (0..511).map{|i|("%09b"%i).tr("01",".X").gsub(/.../){$&+$/}}*$/
```

Comment: No need for  `tr`, outputting `0` and `1` is fine. A few more suggestions `512.times{|i|$><<("%09b"%i).gsub(/.../){$&+$/}+$/}` 50 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 80 bytes

```
for i in range(512):print("\n".join(format(i,'09b')[j:j+3]for j in(0,3,6)),"\n")
```

I managed to outgolf someone :)

Comment: Save a byte using a while loop: `i=512` newline
`while i:print("\n".join(format(i,'09b')[j:j+3]for j in(0,3,6)),"\n");i-=1`

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 55 bytes

```
for(;$c<512;)echo chunk_split(sprintf("%09b ",$c++),3);
```

uses `0` and `1`. Run with `-r`.

Comment: I just love the way I impletemented the separating newline :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
print set(combinations('X.'*9,9))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1chsyS1qCQ/P6dYITO3IL@oRIuroCgzr0ShOLVEIzk/NykzL7EkMz@vWEM9Qk9dy1LHUlPz/38A)

Returns the 512 configurations as a set object in python. Refer to ungolfed version to make output more readable.

Ungolfed Version to make output more readable:

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 121 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
for i in set(combinations('X.'*9,9)):
	for j in range(3):print''.join(list(i))[j*3:(j*3)+3]
	print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDsIgEADQuXwFGweaDjKVLzExDtVQPVLuyHGLX4/W5U2vffTNdBljE64WNYsy791ibSwazMZi0SLZnhWeXB9IqyJTB3edXVjOi/fJTEcrR5OVXhmiT02Q1Lm5MBLs2BXQ@1sJMcEPf4p3M/3PGF8)

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 2, 92 bytes

Int to binary string in Swift takes up too many chars so I just use two nested loops...

```
var s="";for x in 0..<512{(0..<9).map{s+=($0%3==0 ?"\n":"")+"\(x>>$0&1)"};s+="\n-"};print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C - 97 bytes

```
i;main(j){for(;i++<512;)for(j=0;j++<13;)putchar(j%4&&j<13?i%(1<<j-j/4)>(1<<j-j/4-1)-1?88:46:10);}
```

Basically prints the example output from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <strike>123</strike> <strike>121</strike> <strike>109</strike> 103 bytes

Here is my old one:

```
import itertools
[print(a+b+c,d+e+f,g+h+i,'\n',sep='\n') for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i in itertools.product(['X','.'],repeat=9)]
```

And here is my new one:

```
import itertools as i
[print(a[:3],a[3:6],a[6:],'\n',sep='\n') for a in i.product(['X','.'],repeat=9)]
```

This prints extra characters but the OP said ASCII art is allowed which implies multiple characters are fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Prolog (SWI), 98 bytes

Output is a list of 3x3 matrices containing the elements 0 and 1.

```
r([]).
r([H|T]):-between(0,1,H),r(T).
p(Y):-Z=[[_,_,_],[_,_,_],[_,_,_]],findall(Z,maplist(r,Z),Y).
```

[Online interpreter](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/DEEQVgbL.pl)

I feel like the matrix generation could be shorter.
It should be possible to fit the between in a forall or something similar, but I can't figure out how.

Golfing tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```
print$_/9&1<<$_%9?1:0,$/x(!(++$_%3)+!($_%9))for+0..4607
```

Output:

```
000
000
000

100
000
000
...
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
512+ḶBḊ€s€3Y€j“¶¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@29qaKT9cMc2p4c7uh41rSkGYuNIIJH1qGHOoW2Htv3/DwA)

Uses `01`. Because of a bug in `⁾`, I had to use `“¶¶` instead of `⁾¶¶`, because otherwise, instead of two newlines, two pilcrows would have showed up in the output. As you can see, though, that didn't cost me any bytes at all.

K beats this, so this must be further golfed down.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
žAFNžA+b¦3ô»,¶?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390n6ObH5DQTjq0zPjwlkO7dQ5ts///HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## **Python 3, 74 bytes**

```
i=512;b="\n"
while i:i-=1;a=format(i,'09b');print(a[:3]+b+a[3:6]+b+a[6:],b)
```

Just a little shorter than Destructible Lemon's answer

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 32 bytes

```perl
$_=("{.,#}"x3 .$/)x3;say<"$_\n">
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZDqVpPR7lWqcJYQU9FX7PC2Lo4sdJGSSU@Jk/J7v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
T3ã¶«3ãJ»
```

Uses the digits `[1,0]`. The `T` could be replaced with `₂`, `₃`, or `₆` to use the digits `[2,6]`, `[9,5]`, or `[3,6]` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xPjw4kPbDq0GUl6Hdv//DwA)

Outputting as an unformatted list could have been **5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**: [`T3ã3ã`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xPjwYiD6/x8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
T          # Push 10
 3ã        # Take the cartesian power of 3 with its digits:
           #  ["111","110","101",...,"000"]
   ¶«      # Append a newline to each triplet
           #  ["111\n","110\n","101\n",...,"000\n"]
     3ã    # Take the cartesian power of 3 with this list of strings:
           #  [["111\n","111\n","111\n"],["111\n","111\n","110\n"],...,["000\n","000\n","000\n"]]
       J   # Join each inner list together
           #  ["111\n111\n111\n","111\n111\n110\n",...,"000\n000\n000\n"]
        »  # And join that list by newlines
           #  "111\n111\n111\n\n111\n111\n110\n\n...\n000\n000\n000\n"
           # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
512.times{puts ("%09b"%_1).scan(/.../),$/}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN7VMDY30SjJzU4urC0pLihU0lFQNLJOUVOMNNfWKkxPzNPT19PT0NXVU9GshOqAaYQYAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `s`, <strike>12</strike> 8 bytes

```
₀2(3ẋ“¶+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJzIiwiIiwi4oKAMigz4bqL4oCcwrYrIiwiIiwiIiwiMy40LjEiXQ==)
port of the 05ab1e answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 12 bytes

```
≡(↯3_3)⋯⇡512
```

Outputs an array of 512 3x3 bit matrices. Makes clever use of the `bits ⋯` primitive, which converts all numbers in an array to lists of bits.

With `&gifs`, you can make a very tiny GIF cycling every grid.

[Pad, GIF version](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__4omhKOKGrzNfMynii6_ih6E1MTIgIyBNYWluIGNvZGUKJmdpZnMgMTIK)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `Hj`, 62 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 7.75 bytes

```
U2(3ÞẊṅ¶+
```

```
U2(3ÞẊṅ¶+­⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
# ‎⁡#H flag sets stack to 100
U          # ‎⁢uniquify the digits, getting a list of [1,0]. This didn't work with the builtin for 10 when I tried it
 2(        # ‎⁣iterate twice
   3ÞẊ     # ‎⁤cartesian power of 3
      ṅ¶+  # ‎⁢⁡joined on nothing with a newline appended
# ‎⁢⁢j flag joins top of stack on newlines
# ‎⁢⁣this leads to the double newline separator
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJIaj0iLCIiLCJVMigzw57huorhuYXCtisiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Bitstring:

```
01100100111011000111001100111101010001110000111111010101000100
```

Port of Kevin's 05ab1e answer, with different separators.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 52 bytes

```
printf+("%03b
"x3).$/,$_&7,$_/8&7,$_>>6&7 for 0..511
```

or 54 bytes:

```
print map$_.$/,sprintf('%09b',$_)=~/.../g,''for 0..511
```

or Perl 5.14+, 48 bytes:

```
say sprintf('%09b',$_)=~s/.../$&\n/gr for 0..511
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
echo@<"2'.X'{~_3]\"1#:i.512
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I9/BRslIXS9Cvbou3jg2RslQ2SpTz9TQ6P9/AA)

Comment: The problem isn't restrictive on output format, so you could use `echo _3]\"1#:i.512`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 72 bytes

```
time {puts [regsub -all (...) [format %09b [expr [incr i]-1]] \&\n]} 512
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgFAXAq7xNUQslgxadRf9CxUJQEzUIorPbTLOh9@ajw5vvViGLO@ttwHQImDjnM@RxlagbhmU3kO7JBdInW@CJCSKoUSX6sIm19x8)

Comment: Failed outgolf: https://tio.run/##JcNBCoAgEAXQfaf4i1wGWbToLDoLHQyENFGDIDq7BcF7lffWqg8Od2ETobYjB1MhxtVCuStlKB85w9MgiQhiLj8YWHCXzlrQGx17@2UdHyxyau0F

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
#f4o8³_¤Åò3 ·+R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/XznNJN/i0Ob4Q0sOtx7eZKxwaLt20P//ukEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes

```python
from itertools import *
for i in product(".X",repeat=9):
    i="".join(i);print i[0:3]+"\n"+i[3:6]+"\n"+i[6:]+"\n"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcZBCsJADAXQfU8RsmqtFLFQcKT3EKoL0Sl@sUmIceHpR0HwrZ6946ayLWV2XQiRPVQfT8Ji6kGralYnEITM9fq6RM3dgdeeLZ9j3DWpoi@MzN1dITWavTkkCNMm9aeWj8Itpj4N/w/p11I@)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

```javascript
h=console.log;f=u=>h(u/4&1,u/2&1,u&1)|u/8;for(i=0;i<512;h``)f(f(f(i++)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/wzY5P684PydVLyc/3TrNttTWLkOjVN9EzVCnVN8IRKoZataU6ltYp@UXaWTaGlhn2pgaGllnJCRopmmAYKa2tqam5n9rJHM03DRMdYw1NYDCAA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
for(i=0;i<512;f(f(f(i++))))f=u=>console.log(u/4&1,u/2&1,u&1)|u/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PWwDrTxtTQyDpNAwQztbU1gSDNttTWLjk/rzg/J1UvJz9do1TfRM1Qp1TfCESqGWrWlOpb/LdGVuGmYapjrKmhqfkfAA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 75 bytes

```javascript
for(i=511;++i<1024;f(f(f(i))))f=u=>console.log(u.toString(2).slice(-3))|u/8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/Lb9II9PW1NDQWls708bQwMjEOk0DBDM1gSDNttTWLjk/rzg/J1UvJz9do1SvJD@4pCgzL13DSFOvOCczOVVD11hTs6ZU3@K/NbJKNw1THWNNDU3N/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 48 bytes

```perl
say((sprintf"%09b",$_)=~s%...%$&$/%gr)for 0..511
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJDo7igKDOvJE1J1cAySUlHJV7Ttq5YVU9PT1VFTUVfNb1IMy2/SMFAT8/U0PD//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)